# Are partially cooked foods subject to bishul/Pat akum

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, yoreh-deah, bishul-akum, pat-yisrael

According to Halacha, are foods which are otherwise subject to bishul/pat akum laws (particularly if one is normally stringent with them) that are partially but not fully cooked by a gentile considered bishul/Pat akum?

Or since they are not fully cooked, if a Jew finishes cooking them, are they not bishul/Pat akum after the fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OU Kosher answers your question ([here](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/at-what-point-does-food-cooked-by-a-nochri-become-bishul-akum/)) and states it is a dispute between Ashkenazi and Sefaradi *poskim*

> **Rav Yosef Caro** (Shulchan Aruch YD 113:9) writes that **if a nochri [non-Jew] cooks
> food to the point of maachal ben Drusai (the minimum level of
> edibility), it is subject to bishul Akum**. Food that is cooked less
> than this amount is permitted, since it is not yet edible. **Once cooked
> till maachal ben Drusai, the food is bishul Akum and remains forbidden
> even if a Jew completes the cooking**. However, the Beis Efraim quotes
> the Avkas Rochel (a collection of teshuvos from the Beis Yosef) who
> writes that if the nochri cooked the food past maachal ben Drusai and
> subsequently it dried out and could not be eaten without further
> cooking, the prohibition of bishul Akum is removed.
>
> **The Rema** (YD 113:9) **disagrees with Rav Yosef Caro**. In his opinion,
> **food cooked by an aino Yehudi may be eaten if a Yisroel completes the
> cooking process**. In this respect, bishul Akum is different than most
> other prohibitions which cannot be reversed. Apparently, the Rema’s
> position is that when the Yisroel completes the cooking process the
> initial prohibition of bishul Akum is lifted because the food is no
> longer the same as before. Food cooked by a Jew cannot be considered
> bishul Akum.
>
> The Issur V’heter (43:11) adds that this leniency (of the Rama) only
> applies if there is further cooking which improves the food, but
> reheating does not change the status.

OU Kosher notes [elsewhere](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/playing-with-fire/#:%7E:text=What%20if%20the%20gentile%20cooks,to%20be%20considered%20bishul%20yisrael.) that

> Many kosher agencies who follow the Ashkenazic tradition of the Rama
> allow non-Jewish companies to prepare specific types of food that
> cannot be used out of the container without further processing. Since
> these items will require additional cooking in any event, it is
> assumed that the final stages will be done by a Jew and the product
> will then be considered bishul yisrael